# single quotes and double quotes in php?

Tags: php

**Double quotes--->"$a"** interpretes variables.

**single quotes--->'$a'** does not.Alright till now

**MyQuestion:**

- what if I use `"'$a'"`?

*Note*:want to know behind the scene details.

*Detailed Explanation*:

I faced a major problem because of this when I used it in a foreach loop:

The following example gave me incorrect option value. For example, value it renders is UX if original is UX developer

```
echo "<option value=".$item['m_designation'].">".$item['m_designation']."</option>";
```

this example gave me correct option value. For example,value it renders is UX developer if original is UX developer

```
 echo '<option value="'.$item['m_designation'].'"> '.$item['m_designation'].' </option>';
```

Hope I am clear.

**Update:**

I got the desired result but I don't know the logic behind it. I have tried it and done it successfully, but I wanted to know what's happening behind the scene. I think people have misread my question.

Comment: `What will be the result?` --> [try it out](https://eval.in) and you'll know soon enough.

Comment: I have done it,but i wanted to know whats happening behind the scene..I got the desired result but i dont know the logic behind

Comment: That is a very common way to generate quoted strings from variables ... As HamZa said: try it out! The logic? The `'` inside the `"`-delimited strings are just *normal* characters, so *nothing special* happens here ...

Comment: @VAGABOND The logic is simple, when you use double quotes, all what's inside will get interpreted. Single quotes inside double quotes are *mere characters*, so they don't interfer or do anything special.

Comment: @HamZa:please read my question..I have tried it

Comment: @VAGABOND You gave me the option to ignore the rest :)

Comment: @VAGABOND People are indeed misreading (or not reading) parts of your question - I believe I have understood it however. Check out my answer below and see if that helps.

Comment: @HamZa:Ohh,my mistake...but just wanted to know the behaviour...i think people got me wrong..

Comment: @VAGABOND I shall point you to read this [whole section about strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) from the manual.

Comment: @HamZa:why dint you post it as answer..i think i was looking for that..

Comment: @VAGABOND Link only answers aren't encouraged. What if the link died ? Links have to come with a short debriefing or explanation. If you ever feel like the question is too basic, don't forget we have [chatrooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) to point you to some links or some discussions :)

Comment: @VAGABOND Well you can enter [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and use the search option to search for specific chatrooms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `'` and `"` for strings only changes when they are the outer container of the entire string - a different quote inside that is just treated as a plain character with no special meaning, therefore `"'$var'"` uses the rules of `"` (parsing variables), whereas `'"$var"'` would literally output `"$var"` as it uses the rules of `'` (no parsing of variables).

**Summary:**
When you do `"''"` or `"\"\""` the quotes inside the string are not parsed by PHP and treated as literal characters, the contents of such quotes will have the same behaviour in or out of those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a string that uses double quotes as delimiters and has single quotes as data. The delimiters are the ones that matter for determining how a string will be handled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question is more directed toward the output PHP produces for HTML formatting. Simply, single quotes in PHP represent the literal value:

```
$a = 1;
$b = '$a';
echo $b;
//$a

$a = 1;
$b = "$a";
echo $b;
//1

$a = 1;
$b = "'$a'";
echo $b;
//'1'
```

If you want to output HTML, you can use [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). This is useful when outputting more than one line containing variables:

```
$name = "Bob";
$age = 59;
echo <<<EOT
My name is "$name".
I am $age years old.
EOT;
//My name is "Bob"
//I am 59 years old.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = 'test';

echo '$a';// prints $a 
echo "$a";// prints test
echo "'$a'"//prints 'test'
```

double quotes checks the php variable and echo the string with php variable value

example `echo "wow $a  123"; //prints wow test 123`

single quotes print whatever in the single quotes

example `echo 'foo $a 123';//prints foo $a 123`

Comment: try to understand the php concepts, dont confuse with your outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'faulty' (first) string was *missing the single quotes* `'`:

```
echo "<option value='".$item['m_designation']."'>".$item['m_designation']."</option>";
                    ^                          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you confuse the quotes in your HTML with the quotes in the PHP.

```
$a = 1;
$b = '"$a"';
echo $b;
# => "$a"

$a = 1;
$b = "\"$a\"";
echo $b;
# => "1"
```

I'd advise you to simply *never* use string literals, as (especially in PHP) there are a lot of unexpected and weird edge-cases to them. Best is to force an interpreter (which also only works with double quotes:

```
$a = 1;
$b = "\"{$a}\"";
$c = "{$a+2}";
echo $b;
# => "1"
echo $c;
# => 3
```