# Variable not substituting value. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php

In the following code fragment, the value of $key (line 39) is not being substituted.  Can someone suggest why?

The variable is receiving the correct value as I have debugged for that in line 37 and it is correct.

If I replace the variable with an integer then the code run correctly i.e. it opens the form and executes a query returning the expected records.

Why will the substitution not take place within php and what must I do for the substitution to take place?

Thanks in advance.

```
 37 //var_dump($key);
 38 //echo "<br>";
 39 header( 'Location: http://xx.x.80.94/ants/connie/allExhibitsForEvent.php?id=$key' );
 40 ?>
```

Comment: If anything this should have been closed as a typo. The duplicate question doesn't address single vs. double quoted strings.

Comment: I was going to VTC for that reason, but the reason also says 'is not helpful for future users' - this question likely is helpful.

Comment: This is a better duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18357786/single-quotes-and-double-quotes-in-php

Comment: no problem let me reopen .... btw i could not cast close again :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the $key inside of a single quoted string.. Try to use the double quote and it will works well.

```
header( "Location: http://xx.x.80.94/ants/connie/allExhibitsForEvent.php?id=$key" );
```

Comment: Vote up the answer? haha lol

Answer (score 2):

[If you want string interpolation of variables, use double quotes:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

```
header( "Location: http://xx.x.80.94/ants/connie/allExhibitsForEvent.php?id=$key" );
```

Comment: I'm surprised an 8k user would post an answer to this question instead of finding its duplicate and voting to close...

Comment: it's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: It was quicker to type the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 alternatives

```
1. Change `'` to `"` so that it becomes
header( "Location: http://xx.x.80.94/ants/connie/allExhibitsForEvent.php?id=$key" );

2. Use something like this
header( 'Location: http://xx.x.80.94/ants/connie/allExhibitsForEvent.php?id='.$key );
```